# Uploading JSON file to an existing row in DynamoDB table

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm new to AWS and Python, I need to upload a JSON file to an existing table row.
I have a table with a composite primary key, and 4 columns with data. There's a need to add a 5th column, and append JSON file to a specified item in that table.
I've figured out how to find the file in the system, but I'm not sure how to append it to a specific item. If the table is noSQL, does it mean that I can just create another column on the fly without removing and redeploying the table?

How do I find the item and append JSON to it? I believe put_item won't work because it creates a new entry

Comment: "If the table is noSQL, does it mean that I can just create another column on the fly without removing and redeploying the table?" Yes, exactly. Especially since you are updating a "Record" with a new "Attribute". This isn't SQL, so "rows" and "columns" aren't even the correct terms to use here..

Comment: Examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of put_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item) it replaces the old item. If you don't want to upload the entire item, you could also use [update_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item).